# htaccess restrict authentification but exception on file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've seen a few other relative posts but didn't find any solution.

I need to restrict a folder with authentification, it works.
But in this folder I need to keep one file access opened to everybody, I used this but it doesn't works :

```
AuthName "Admins Only"
AuthUserFile /home/dd/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType basic
require user AuthorizedUser
Options -Indexes
<Files "admin-ajax.php">
   Allow from all
   Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SetEnv and Order directive :

```
#set variable if uri is "/admin-ajax.php"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/folder/admin-ajax\.php noauth=1

#auth 
AuthName "Admins Only"
AuthUserFile /home/dd/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType basic
require user AuthorizedUser

 #Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require user AuthorizedUser
Allow from env=noauth
```

This will let you access your **admin-ajax.php** without login to server.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. 
If I try to access this file I still have the login window that appears. Should I use the complete serveur url : `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/home/dd/admin-ajax\.php noauth=1` ?

Comment: What is the full url of **admin-ajax.php**?

Comment: Is your admin-ajax.php file in root folder?

Comment: The file **admin-ajax.php** is located in a subfolder, not in root folder : `/home/www/folder/admin-ajax.php`. The root folder of the website is `/home/www/`. I updated the url in the main post to make it a bit more understandable^^.

Comment: I  edited my answer, replace **folder** with the name of your **subfolder** in **SetenvIf** line

Comment: @Nonoseki you are welcome! glad to hear it worked out. You can accept the answer so that it doesnt show up in unanswered category.